# How to set the BaseScalars of a CoordSys3D() to be real in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to symbolically calculate the inner product of two spatially dependent quantum states using sympy. For example (in Jupyter Notebook):

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import  CoordSys3D, gradient

phi_l, k = symbols('\phi_l k', real=True)
k1, k2, k3, k4, k5 = np.eye(5) # Basis states of the Hilbert space states are in.
R = CoordSys3D('R')
psi = sin(phi_l)*exp(-1j*4*k*R.x)*k1 - cos(phi_l)*exp(-1j*(3*R.x+R.y)*k)*k2
# R.x, R.y, R.z are the BaseScalars of the Coordinate system
np.dot(psi.conjugate(), psi)
```

outputs

[image]

Though this is correct and suffices for me, I'd like to know how to set the `BaseScalars` `R.x, R.y` and `R.z` as real. This will simplify my expression to 1. I checked the source of `CoordSys3D`. It seems like I have to inherit this class and modify the `__init__` method myself. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, it is not possible to set assumptions on base scalars. In your case, going with OOP and implement a different behaviour might end up to be a nightmare.

This is how I would do it: substitute the base scalar with ordinary symbols with assumptions:

```
expr = np.dot(psi.conjugate(), psi)
xr, yr, zr = R.base_scalars()
x, y, z = symbols("x:z", real=True)
expr.subs({xr:x , yr:y, zr: z}).simplify()

# out: 1.0
```